# "Invalid memory address" in Golang using ioutil.ReadAll()

Tags: http, pointers, go

I'm currently learning Golang (and so far I love it). But unfortunately, I've been stuck for a couple hours and I don't seem to find any solution to my problem on Google.

So here's my problem. I have this piece of code (from a tutorial) :

```
func main() {
    var s SitemapIndex

    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)

    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        resp, _ := http.Get(Location)
        ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    }

}
```

I know, my code is incomplete but that's because I deleted the parts that were not causing the problem to make it more readable on Stackoverflow.

So when I get the content of `Location` and try to process the data with `ioutil.ReadAll()` I get this error mentioning a pointer :

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x1210a69]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/tom/Developer/Go/src/news/index.go:23 +0x159
exit status 2
```

I really don't understand this error, no matter how much I look into it. I tried to pull the error from `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` by doing `_, e := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` and then printing `e`, but doing that throws *another* error...

I read somewhere that it can be because the body returned to me has errors, but it's working fine in the tutorial.

Hopefully you guys will have a solution for me. Thanks.

EDIT : Here are the structs I have defined :

```
type SitemapIndex struct {
    Locations []string `xml:"sitemap>loc"`
}

type News struct {
    Titles []string `xml:"url>news>title"`
    Keywords []string `xml:"url>news>keywords"`
    Locations []string `xml:"url>loc"`
}

type NewsMap struct {
    Keyword string
    Location string
}
```

Comment: can you copy the SitemapIndex to check ?

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the post

Comment: You ignored errors this way nobody can findout the problem. Instead of discarding the errors handle them. like this. resp,er := http.Get("your address");if err!= nil { log.Fataln(err) }

Comment: Cross posted: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/im-a-beginner-i-get-errors-parsing-a-url-with-http-get/11948/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've found the reason for my problem and how to solve it. The problem was that the url had some newlines I didn't see.

So instead of doing this :

```
resp, err := http.Get(Location)
```

I did this :

```
resp, err := http.Get(strings.TrimSpace(Location))
```

That solved it.

Answer (score 5):

**The First Rule of Go: Check for errors.**

---

> When a function call returns an error, it’s the caller’s
>   responsibility to check it and take appropriate action.
>
> Usually when a function returns a non-nil error, its other results are
>   undefined and should be ignored.
>
> [The Go Programming Language, Alan A. A. Donovan and  Brian W.
>   Kernighan](https://www.gopl.io/)

---

For example,

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", Location) // debug error
    fmt.Println(resp)            // debug error
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Output:

```
"\nhttps://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml\n"
<nil>
parse 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
```

If you don't catch this error and keep going with `resp == nil` then

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type SitemapIndex struct {
    Locations []string `xml:"sitemap>loc"`
}

func main() {
    var s SitemapIndex

    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    err = xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        resp, err := http.Get(Location)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%q\n", Location) // debug error
            fmt.Println(resp)            // debug error
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(len(bytes))
        err = resp.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mostafa mentioned , you have to handle the errors properly. There is no try catch in golang. 
Something like this i have tired. 
atleast it catpures url error is in liteIde

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

type SitemapIndex struct {
    Locations []string `xml:"sitemap>loc"`
}

func main() {
    var s SitemapIndex

    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to get the url ")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    //fmt.Println(string(bytes))
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)
    //fmt.Println(len(s.Locations))

    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        //fmt.Println(Location)
        go func() {
            r, err := http.Get(Location)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error occured ", err)
                return
            }
            bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error in reading :", err)
            }
            fmt.Println(string(bytes))
            r.Body.Close()
        }()
    }
    runtime.Gosched()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I printed the error as I was told to do, and it said `first path segment in URL cannot contain colon`. The response is `<nil>` btw. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: I made test code with goroutine but you may have to try it without goroutine . debug each charater in print to see if any additional char is added with location url.

Comment: The error says that something wrong with URL that needs to be look into .  How we are wrting to buffer or stiring , needed to make sure it does not have any other chars than the url itself

Comment: I tried it, added `runtime.Gosched()` in the end, but it didn't solve the problem. What does this line do btw ?

Comment: ok , what i am suggesting is , look at the URL (location url ) in range loop and check if it is added with any additional quotes or something else . The runtime.Goshed() call make sure the main program dont quit until all goroutine finishes off

Comment: As for the url, the err shows me the url that Golang is using. Here's the error : `https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon`. So the url seems ok...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185788/discussion-between-tomfl-and-cslrnr).